# How to stop browser navigating in csharp for windowsphone

Tags: c#, windows-phone

I want to stop browser navigating,when i click button.I tried in the below method but it doesn't worked.

```
    private void webBrowser1_Navigating(object sender, NavigatingEventArgs e)
    {
        button2.Click += new RoutedEventHandler((object caller,System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs f) =>
        { 
            e.Cancel = true;
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one-

```
private void webBrowser_Navigating(object sender, NavigatingEventArgs e)
    {
        stop.IsEnabled=true;
        stop.Click += new RoutedEventHandler((object caller, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs f) =>
        {
            stopPressed = true;
        });

        if (stopPressed == true)
            e.Cancel = true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stop the browser navigating you can try like this:

```
       private void stop_Tap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
        {
            MiniBrowser.InvokeScript("eval", "document.execCommand('Stop');");
        }
```